# How to deal with a comma (,) in Json String To DataTable conversion?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

On my asp.net web application I am using a function to **convert Json String to Data Table**.Function throughs an error while dealing data with a comma(,) in it.
I got the error from : `string ColumnsNameString = ColumnsNameData.Substring(0, idx - 1).Replace("\"", "");`

[image]

This is the **C# Function** I am using:

```
public class ConvertJsonStringToDataTable
{
    public DataTable JsonStringToDataTable(string jsonString)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        if (jsonString != "[]" && jsonString != "undefined")
        {
            string[] jsonStringArray = Regex.Split(jsonString.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", ""), "},{");
            List<string> ColumnsName = new List<string>();

            foreach (string jSA in jsonStringArray)
            {
                string[] jsonStringData = Regex.Split(jSA.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", ""), ",");
                foreach (string ColumnsNameData in jsonStringData)
                {
                    if (ColumnsNameData != "")
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            int idx = ColumnsNameData.IndexOf(":");
                            string ColumnsNameString = ColumnsNameData.Substring(0, idx - 1).Replace("\"", "");
                            if (!ColumnsName.Contains(ColumnsNameString))
                            {
                                ColumnsName.Add(ColumnsNameString);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            throw new Exception(string.Format("Error Parsing Column Name : {0}", ColumnsNameData));
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }

            foreach (string AddColumnName in ColumnsName)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(AddColumnName);
            }

            foreach (string jSA in jsonStringArray)
            {
                string[] RowData = Regex.Split(jSA.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", ""), ",");
                DataRow nr = dt.NewRow();
                foreach (string rowData in RowData)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int idx = rowData.IndexOf(":");
                        string RowColumns = rowData.Substring(0, idx - 1).Replace("\"", "");
                        string RowDataString = rowData.Substring(idx + 1).Replace("\"", "");
                        nr[RowColumns] = RowDataString;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(nr);
            }
            return dt;
        }

        return dt;
    }
}
```

A portion of **Jquery Function**

```
var IdentificationMark = $("[id*=txtIdentificationMark]").val();
var Remarks = $("[id*=txtRemarks]").val();

var dataCustMaster = { IdentificationMark: IdentificationMark, Remarks: Remarks };
var DataCustMaster = (JSON.stringify(dataCustMaster));

if (hasError == false) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "CustomerCreation.aspx/InsertDetails",
    data: "{'dataAuthOper':'" + AuthOperData + "','dataAdds':'" + AddsData + "','dataId':'" + IdData + "','dataCustMaster':'" + DataCustMaster + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: OnSuccess,
    failure: function (response) {
    alert(response.d);
  }

  });
  function OnSuccess(response, userContext, methodName) {
      location.reload(true);
      alert("Saved");
       }
  }
```

How can I get data with comma(,) ? How can I solve this issue ?? what are the changes I needed to make ??
 Help me please,I am a beginner..

Comment: can you show a sample of your json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that a call to `.Substring(0, idx-1)` is returning a value less than 0.

You should make sure that `idx` is greater than or equal to 0.

```
int idx = ColumnsNameData.IndexOf(":");

if (idx == -1) 
{
    // Do something here. You can throw an exception or return
}

string ColumnsNameString = ColumnsNameData.Substring(0, idx - 1).Replace("\"", "");
if (!ColumnsName.Contains(ColumnsNameString))
{
    ColumnsName.Add(ColumnsNameString);
}
```

#### UPDATE

The above code is still relevant for your problem. However, you will need to detect when a comma is located within double quotes. The reason your code is failing is the `Split` line which creates an array of strings with comma as a splitting point. It finds every single comma and splits the string along those lines.

You cannot rely on a built-in method `Split` to do this. You'll have to write your own method for parsing the string. If you want to got the easier route, replace the comma separator in your Ajax call and use a different separator like pipe |, hash #, or something else.

Comment: `if(idx== -1)` will break the function but i need the data with comma.Data Like address have separations with comma(,)..how can i get that ??